# javascript Trying to copy database generated text in selectbox to textbox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a chained dropdown that contain continent, region,country, province,city,district, and village, but i'm stuck at country.

my dropdown require me to use the id from database to chain all the dropdown, so to get the text name i usually using this method :

Country :

```
<select name="loc_country" class="loc_country loc5" id="loc_country" onchange="javacript: var valor2 = this.options[selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('loc_country_real').value = valor2;">
<option value="0">-Select-</option>
</select>                   
<input type="text" id="loc_country_real" name="loc_country_real">
```

However this method doesn't work this time so i try another approach with :

```
  <select name="loc_country" class="loc_country loc5" id="loc_country">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
    </select>
 <input type="text" id="loc_country_real" name="loc_country_real">
```

and js :

```
$("#continent").change(function () {
    $("#loc_country_real").val($('#loc_country').text());
});
```

and hoping when my select box with id="continent" changing, the value will update.
And that method also failed because the value given in "loc_country_real" doesn't match with selectbox "loc_country"
 (e.g.:when i selected europe on the continent selectbox, the loc_country select box will give me a list of  european countries but the value in "loc_country_real" will be asian from country)

i need to make the text in "loc_country" and "loc_country_real" match but i have no idea how to do it, please help.

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Your end statement suggests you just need 2 dropdowns to contain the same values?

Comment: trying to copy text from "loc_country" selectbox to "loc_country" textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Change your select's to have a VALUE matching the text you want E.G:

```
<select name="loc_country" class="loc_country loc5" id="loc_country">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>
```

You can then use `document.getElementById('loc_country').value` to get the selected option value

```
// Change `loc_country_real`'s value to match `loc_country` selected option
document.getElementById('loc_country_real').value = document.getElementById('loc_country').value;
```

Or the jQuery way:

```
$('#loc_country').change(function(){
    $('#loc_country_real').val($('#loc_country').val());
});
```

**Edit since you mentioned you cannot use value:**

```
$('#loc_country').change(function(){
    var textOfSelectedOption = $("#loc_country option:selected").text();
    $('#loc_country_real').val(textOfSelectedOption);
});
```

Comment: like this ?
<br>
$("#continent").change(function () {
    $('#loc_country_real').html($('#loc_country').html());
});
<br>
sorry sir, it doesn't work.

Comment: no it doesn't show any error sir, the value in "loc_country_real" textbox simply doesn't match with the text in "loc_country" (selecting asia still giving me an european country in "loc_country_real")

Comment: @MabroChickenz Sorry I re-read your question, I misunderstood. I'll update my answer

Comment: no sir, sorry i can't do that, the value needs to be id or the next dropdown (which is province) won't show the province link of that country

Comment: @MabroChickenz Check my edit, does not depend on value so you can keep the html as is

Comment: $("#loc_country_real option:selected") ? Sorry sir, but "loc_country_real" is a textbox not a select box.

Comment: @MabroChickenz was a typo. Updated it